# What is a color buffer in OpenGL?

Tags: c, opengl, glut

I am struggling to understand some points in the OpenGL .C code:

- What is this color buffer?
- What are the `glutInitDisplayMode()` and `glClear()` doing to this buffer in the codes below?

```
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGB);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Comment: "*What is this color buffer?*" What is *what* "color buffer"? There are many things which might take on the term "color buffer", so you're going to have to clarify exactly what you're talking about.

Comment: When I search for the specification of the glClear() function in khronos.org I find: glClear — clear buffers to preset values. Which buffer? What is that?

Comment: A [good tutorial](https://learnopengl.com/) will cover all of this (with better alternatives to `glut*`).

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several kinds of buffers in OpenGL. The Color Buffer you're mentioning holds the Color components of the `render target`. The Render target could be an off-screen buffer or a piece of a window, or a back buffer of a window, it depends.

`glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGB)` initializes the render target of the current window. `GLUT_DOUBLE` means, double buffering to avoid flickering. `GLUT_RGB` means, we need memory for colors, without alpha channel.

`glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)` means, only the Color component of the buffer will cleared. You may ask what is the difference. The reasons are, a render target could be split into multiple buffers, for example, a color buffer and the depth-buffer. The depth-buffer would only be cleared if you call `glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)`, you can also combine them via `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)` to clear the color and the depth component at once.

Comment: upvote for what you said, though short it is easier to get it than in many sites. Could you please elaborate it in more words. Especially color buffer.